# YUY2 format video capture using Open CV

Tags: c#, opencv, video-capture

I'm having trouble with Open CV in capturing YUY2 format from a HD 720p webcam. The webcam can support both MJPG and YUY2 format. I want to grab only the YUY2 format from the webcam. I'm using Emgu CV v3.0.0.2157 (cross platform .Net wrapper to the OpenCV image processing ). The function I used to grab the frame from the camera is

```
  frame = capture.QueryFrame();
```

where frame is  (`Mat frame;`).

Is there any way to grab YUY2 format from the camera, whether " QueryFrame() " can grab YUY2 format.

I have also set the Camera Format to YUY2 before capturing, mentioned below:

```
capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FourCC, 0x32595559);
```

where 0x32595559 is the Fourcc for YUY2, but no use, it's still unable to capture MJPG format.